# Concatenating bytes to strings

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to save two strings to the EEPROM, separating each one with a 255 (or 0) char so later I can read them knowing when each string ends.

```
void saveToE(String data) {
  int str_len = data.length() + 1; 
  char char_array[str_len];
  data.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);
  for(int addr = 0; addr < str_len; addr++){
    EEPROM.write(addr, char_array[addr]);
  }
}
```

The problem is the concatenation of data:

```
String part1 = "Hello";
String part2 = "World";
String data = part1 + byte 255 + part2 + byte255;
```

How can I add the byte 255 after part1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it using string concatenation, like this:

```
String part1 = "Hello";
String part2 = "World";
String separator = "\xFF"; // That's character 255, in hex
String data = part1 + separator + part2 + separator;
```

You could also do the concatenation right in your `saveToE` function, like this:

```
void saveTwoStringsToE(String one, String two) {
  int str_len1 = one.length(); 
  int str_len2 = two.length(); 
  // Add two bytes for 255 separators, and an extra byte for null terminator
  char char_array[str_len1+str_len2+3];
  one.toCharArray(char_array, str_len1);
  char_array[str_len1] = 255;
  two.toCharArray(char_array+str_len1+1, str_len2);
  char_array[str_len1+1+str_len2] = 255;
  for(int addr = 0; addr < str_len1+str_len2; addr++) {
    EEPROM.write(addr, char_array[addr]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a thing in C.  C++, sure.   Is this question tagged appropriately?

Comment: @BrianMcFarland My understanding is that this is part of the Arduino library, which I think is on top of C++. Here is a [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAppendOperator) to the doc that I think is relevant here.

Comment: From that page, seeing a function declared `void setup()` instead of `void setup(void)` is enough to make it pretty obvious this is not `C`.  Then `Serial.begin(9600);` pretty much seals the deal.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland I poked around the manual pages at the link, and it looks like they've got their own language, which is based on a subset of C++.

Comment: You are right, this is C++, the questions has been edited. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
char separator_char[1];
separator_char[0] = 255;
String separator_string = String(separator_char);
```

Then you should be able to use the string as separotor how you planned it.